# How to change the ratio of movement of a driver?

Tags: drivers

I have set up a driver which causes an object's z location to controller the other objects x rotation. It works, but I have to move the driver a long way in order to get only a slight change on the driven objects rotation. How do I change this ratio so that the driven object is affected more by less movement of the driver?

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply multiply the driver value.

1. Select the driven object and go to *Drivers* editor
2. Click your Driver (mine is called Z Euler Rotation)
3. Go to *Sidebar (N) > Modifiers > Generator* and add a multiplier value

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help :).