# Driver rotating driven object in the wrong direction?

Tags: drivers

I have set up a driver to rotate an object on its x axis by moving the driver on it z axis. I want to rotate the driven object in a certain direction when moving the driver up and of course in the other direction when moved down. The problem is that these directions are reversed - the driven object rotates the opposite direction in which I want it to rotate when moving the driver. How can I reverse this so that the object rotates in the desired direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply the driver by -1 using the *Generator modifier*.
This will effectively invert the values.

<sub>[Original answer on how to set up driver modifiers.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185753/78972)</sub>

[image]

Comment: Sorted - thank you!